# Direction of particles in a longitudinal wave

Tags: homework-and-exercises, waves

[image]

For this question the answer key says it is A. However I think it should be B. At T=0 the particles will be headed towards the node. Given that the equillibrium points happen when T=T/4 it would make sense that the particles at T=0 to be farther apart then move inwards.

I even tried to look at a simulation which seems to validate my thinking:

[image]

[image]

So shouldn't the answer be B not A?

Comment: From whence is this problem? The author needs some "shade". It shows a transverse wave in a gas, which I just can't [laugh emoji with tear].

Comment: @JEB:  It's pretty clear that the author doesn't think the particles are moving transversely.  The options all involve the particles moving left to right, and the axis for the red curves is labeled as "right/left" at the left end of the top diagram.  It's a *confusing* problem to be sure but I wouldn't presume that the author made a fundamental error.

Comment: Voting to reopen. Obviously not a "do my homework for me" question. The questioner has the answer - they want to understand *why* this is the answer. We should reward their curiosity, not stifle it.

Comment: @MichaelSeifert  but the wave goes up and down, while the answers go side to side. Left to right are "body" coordinate. Idk what left to right means for someone else...it is labeled as up and down. who wrote, edited and published this trash problem? (that's rhetorical, I know who).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solid line in the diagram represents the wave at time $t=0$. The positive $y$ direction (up) is a displacement from the equilibrium position to the right and the negative $y$ direction (down) is a displacement from the equilibrium position to the left. So we can see that at $t=0$ the red particle is displaced to the right of its equilibrium position and the blue particle is displaced to the left of its equilibrium position, while the black particle remains at its equilibrium position. This corresponds with the situation shown in answer A.

Answer B has the right and left displacements reversed.

Answer (score 1):

I think it will be A itself.

The displacement of any particle from its equilibrium position in +ve x direction at a given instant can be obtained visually by imagining a vertical line passing through the particle's **equilibrium position**. The y coordinate of its intersection with the wave diagram gives the signed displacement of the particle along x axis with respect to its equilibrium position.
Let's look at each particle one by one.

The y coordinate of this intersection in case of the red particle is +ve meaning the displacement in x direction is towards right. Hence the red particle at t = 0 will be to the right of its equilibrium position.
As for the yellow particle, the displacement is -ve meaning that it'll be to the left of its mean position.

I hope that clears your doubt.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

The answer is A because it shows zero displacement. The remaining answers show longitudinal displacement, which not possible with a transverse wave, and are thus: a priori wrong.

Comment: There is no suggestion that the wave is transverse. The displacements in the first diagram are labelled "right" and "left", so the implication is that the wave is longitudinal.

Comment: @gandalf61 wait...the right/left are labeling the wave in page coordinates, while drawing them up and down on the page? If I did that at work, I would get laughed out of the room, and probably drug tested. So, back to original comment: who wrote this book? I want names.

Comment: I mean you answer a poorly written question and get down voted. It's common core level stuff. PSE is better than that.